# where to put framework 6 desktop runtime for the setup project

Tags: setup-project, .net-framework-version, visual-studio-2022

Whe building a setup project for a .net 6 console application when trying to make an offline installer I get:

```
ERROR: To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'net6desktopruntime_x64\windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.2-win-x64.exe' for item '.NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.2 (x64)' to your local machine
```

The online installer is working fine.
I downloaded the desktop runtime to the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\net6desktopruntime_x64` as normal (same thing worked for DotNetFX472) but it does not like it

I even tried the other locations like:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\net6desktopruntime_x64
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\net6desktopruntime_x64
```

but no luck any idea where he is looking for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In VS 2022, I found the Boostrapper folder here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\BootstrapperPackages
```

Adding the .exe inside the folder net6desktopruntime_x64 worked for me.

Comment: thanks! I could get it work after hours and hours searching for the solution...

Comment: Thanks for the post!

FYI, it's here if you're not using "Community", then put the *.exe in the appropriate folder. For example, if you require a .net 6 core runtime x64, put it in the "net6coreruntime_x64" subfolder. 

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Msbuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\BootstrapperPackages

Comment: Man I struggled to get this info for +1 hour. I was sure that there was another folder I was not aware about. Thank you a million for this!